# Counterexample of Second fundamental theorem of Calculus if f is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Define $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt$ on $[a,b]$,  then by fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that if $f(x)$ is continuous then $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Say we remove the condition that $f(x)$ is continuous then how would we construct an example such that $F'(x)\neq f(x)$ for finite amount of points? How to come up an example for infinite amount of point?

Thanks

Comment: Literally take a continuous function and then just change its values at finitely many points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=\frac1n\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $F$ is the null function and therefore$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):F'\left(\frac1n\right)\neq f\left(\frac1n\right).$$

Comment: sorry to sound stupid but how can I rigorously show that F is null function? (I have covered up to riemann integration using minorant and majorant so I may not understand some proofs)

Comment: You know that $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Obviously, $F(0)=0$. Now, suppose that $x>0$. Clearly, every lower sum is equal to $0$. On the other hand, given $\varepsilon>0$, it is not hard to prove that there is a partition $P$ of $[0,x]$ such that $\overline\Sigma(f,P)<\varepsilon$. So, $F(x)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a simpler example:

$$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\,,\,\,f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\neq\frac12\\{}\\1,&x=\frac12\end{cases}\implies F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=0\;\;\forall\,x\in[0,1]$$

and thus of course $\;0=F'\left(\frac12\right)\neq1=f\left(\frac12\right)\;$

Answer (score 2):

Start with $f(x)$, then say a new function $g(x)$ equals $f(x)$ for all irrational numbers in your domain, but $g(x) = f(x)+1$ for all rational numbers.  Just one of many ways.